# Convert column data type from VARCHAR to DATE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a column with VARCHAR data type which have dates(values) as strings like dd/mm/yyyy

I want to change its data type to DATE and want to preserve the entered dates(value) when I try to do it, like:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 DATE;
```

I lose the strings and the values get converted to 0000.00.00

How can I change the column data type without losing my data.

Comment: Please add some sample data showing what the text date values look like.  We can't help you without seeing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would,

1. Add a temporal column

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD temp_date DATE;
```

2. Update this temporal column casting the value `CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE)`

```sql
UPDATE t1 SET temp_date=CAST(yourvarcharcol AS DATE) WHERE 1;
```

3. Update the original column type

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY yourvarcharcol DATE;
```

4. Update the original column with the temporal column.

```sql
UPDATE t1 SET yourvarcharcol=temp_date WHERE 1;
```

5. Remove the temporal column

```sql
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN temp_date
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: thankx @Erubiel its working but I m still facing the problem that in myvarchar column my values are in  format like 27/03/2019.

Comment: search for DATE_FORMAT function examples and use this to update your column

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem I solve it with two temporary columns so as not to lose the main values, it is very similar to Erubiel's answer.

Table T1; Original Column "myvarchar"

1.- Insert new columns

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD Temp_ColDate1 VARCHAR;
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD Temp_ColDate2 DATE;
```

2.- n the first column that was added, the cut and armed values were placed according to the DATE form, but in a VARCHAT column

```
UPDATE  T1  SET Temp_ColDate1 = (SELECT CONCAT((SELECT RIGHT(myvarchar, 4)),(SELECT MID(myvarchar, 4, 2)),(SELECT LEFT(myvarchar, 2))))  WHERE 1=1;
```

3.- Then you do a conversion of the values from VARCHAR to DATE in the temporary column 2

```
UPDATE  T1  SET Temp_ColDate2 = (SELECT CONVERT(Temp_ColDate1, DATE))  WHERE 1=1;
```

4.- Delete the temporary column 1

```
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP COLUMN Temp_ColDate1;
```

5.- Remember that the format that you will have in Temp_ColDate1 will be from 0000-00-00 (YYYY-mm-dd), when you need a value just change the presentation format and you're done.

6.- You can delete "myvarchar" and rename "Temp_ColDate2" as "myvarchar"

With this method you can check if there is a problem on any of the dates when you decompose them. I hope it helps you. Note that this is only if the other direct methods do not work.